# Error /dev/net/tun No such device - openvpn

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up openvpn on my chroot debian server.

```
#openvpn --dev tun1 --ifconfig 10.9.8.1 10.9.8.2


Sun Aug 16 18:29:19 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.4 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Sun Aug 16 18:29:19 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013, LZO 2.08
Sun Aug 16 18:29:19 2015 ******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
Sun Aug 16 18:29:19 2015 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)
Sun Aug 16 18:29:19 2015 Exiting due to fatal error
```

---

```
#ll /dev/net/tun 

crw------- 1 root root 10, 200 Apr 23  2014 /dev/net/tun
```

---

```
#cat /dev/net/tun 

cat: /dev/net/tun: No such device
```

So I believe tun module isn't loaded or not enabled on the kernel but I have no idea on how to fix it

Kernel Details are

```
Linux version 2.6.32.12 (root@build3) (gcc version 4.6.4 (Linaro GCC branch-4.6.4. Marvell GCC Dev 201309-2126.3d181f66 64K MAXPAGESIZE ALIGN) ) #4482 Fri Apr 18 02:12:31 CST 2014
```

---

```
#modprobe tun 

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/2.6.32.12/modules.dep.bin'
```

not sure what other details you may need but let me know if you need more.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?